# Invalid Error iabout time moudle in python

Tags: python, time

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
f=open('the data of requests.txt','a+',encoding='utf-8')
end_time=time.strftime('Y%-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(time.time()))
f.write('【time：'+end_time+'】\n【Title】Already have a girlfriend'+'\n')
```

**And this is the error (I guess it's due to the imporper use of strftime**

```
 end_time=time.strftime('Y%-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(time.time()))
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `%Y`, not `Y%`. The percent goes before the specifier.